# Can I rearrange the placement of the items in my inventory?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

When playing video games, I can get pretty pick about things. Specifically, the placement of items in my inventory. For this reason, Skyward Sword is bothering me slightly, since my Slingshot is in the lowermost slot of my <kbd>B</kbd>-activated inventory area, when I feel it should be at the top. Is there any way I can rearrange which items go in what slot, or am are they stuck where you are when you obtain them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can rearrange your used items, such as bottles, your permanent inventory seems to have fixed positions.  This bothered me at one point, when I had gap between two items (despite not obtaining them out of order).

Then again, the only Zelda games you've been able to reorganize your inventory in were the GBC games... which had your sword as one of the items due to the two button limit.

Comment: Yes, but this is the only one that the inventory wasn't paused to select an item...

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto The third, actually... the two DS games both didn't pause when the inventory screen was open.

Comment: Hmmm, well, that's what I get for not playing the DS games...

Answer (score 2):

The tools are put in a pre-determined order it seems. As I have progressed the 12 o'clock position has been kept empty, presumably for the Bow.